# Unable to find SBT plugin for IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I installed scala plugin for IntelliJ Idea 12, but it can't find sbt plugin for it for some reason. Has something changed?

Comment: are you talking about this thing: https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea or this thing: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/ ?

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plugin is not in the default repository, but only in nightlies. Have you followed this (from the [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/) you link to):

> Add the following URL to the list of custom plugin repositories in *Settings | Plugins | Browse Repositories | Manage Repositories*:
>
> [`http://download.jetbrains.com/scala/sbt-nightly-leda.xml`](http://download.jetbrains.com/scala/sbt-nightly-leda.xml)

It worked for me, after I added this repository I found the plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of this plugin, and just installed it myself... and it works.  What tripped me up while installing is that there are a few third party SBT plugins floating around out there as well.  The one you want is called "sbt-intellij-bin-0.1.49" (or some later version).  Not SBT Executor, et al.  Make sure you add the repository referred to on that webpage.

Install, restart IntelliJ.  You should see an 'SBT Console' button along the bottom of the interface.  Nice.. now I don't have to have a terminal window open to SBT taking up screen real estate...